# How to Spawn objects only in a certain radius / unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm very new to programming and i need to make sure that the objects only spawn inside of a certain radius, I've come up with this solution:

```
Vector2 incircle = Random.insideUnitCircle * 10;
```

That works  just fine, but the problem is that I want to make sure that no objects can spawn directly next to the Player. Like a small inner circle where nothing can spawn?

Comment: Like a torus? [Finding random position in torus](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1259394/finding-random-position-in-torus.html), Or inner circle with different center than outer circle? then maybe you can just spawn bunch of positions and choose the positions that not inside the inner circle?

Comment: You can find the answer right here: [How to spawn object around a specific point with specific radius in Unity2D using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041866/how-to-spawn-object-around-a-specific-point-with-specific-radius-in-unity2d-usin/72044327#72044327)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (didn't actually check, but I think that will work)

```
Vector2 incircle = Random.insideUnitCircle * (10 - reservedRadius);
incircle = incircle + incircle.normalized * reservedRadius;
```

Assuming `reservedRadius` is the radius around the player